# Semantic UI rowspan layout

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm new to [semantic ui](http://semantic-ui.com/) and would want to have [this kind of layout](https://jsfiddle.net/szu2ug23/). In [semantic ui's documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#stretched), I was able to find something that does the same but can't get it exactly right.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="ui celled grid container">
  <div class="row stretched equal width">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="ui segment">
        13
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="ui segment">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="ui segment">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="ui segment">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="ui segment">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="ui segment">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60zfcfLx/)

In plain HTML, I am able to do so:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">13</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szu2ug23/)

How would I be able to achieve this layout using semantic ui?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

For responsive design using `div` as requested by OP, modified JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/batrasoe/4k508w9p/

You need to manually override the `padding` property though.

**Non-responsive method:**

You can use the [table collection](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/table.html) classes to modify your HTML code

https://jsfiddle.net/batrasoe/o09mL8kn/1/

```
<table border="1" class="ui unstackable celled table">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">13</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, though I prefer to use `<div>` instead of `<table>` as I need it to be responsive.

Comment: @basagabi modified answer for a responsive solution